# List Posts of a Custom Post Types Ordered by Terms of a Custom Taxonomy?

Tags: custom-post-types

I've created a custom post type and custom taxonomy. I can now create a new post and associate it with a custom category.

The problem is listing these news post types.

This:

```
$loop = new WP_Query( array( 'post_type' => 'sobeedesce' ) );
while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post();
  the_title();
  echo "<br />";
endwhile;`
```

lists all custom posts ok. But I want to list them by category, so adding `'cat' => 12` returns nothing.

I know my custom category id is `12` and I can confirm that by doing

```
$custom_terms = get_the_terms(0, 'cat_sd');
print_r($loop);`
```

inside the loop.

I'm missing something here. Can someone help me?
Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suppose your custom taxonomy slug is 'cat_sd', right?

If so, the right query would be:

```
$loop = new WP_Query( array( 'post_type' => 'sobeedesce', 'cat_sd' => 12 ) );
```

Comment: That put me in the right track, thanks. Just had to change 'cat_sd' => 12 to 'cat_sd' => 'slug_of_this_cat'